# Apache can't determine [REMOTE_ADDR]

Tags: apache, nginx, server, freebsd

I have the FreeBSD server with Nginx as frontend and Apache 2.4 as backend. All work is fine, but Apache can't detect [REMOTE_ADDR] instead it shows server IP address.

To solve my problem I enable

```
LoadModule remoteip_module libexec/apache24/mod_remoteip.so
```

change in httpd.conf

```
#LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%a %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

and try send IP from Nginx to Apache

Nginx conf:

```
server {
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        listen 80;
        disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
        index index.php;
        set $root_path /home/user/example.com/public_html;
        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|js|css|mp3|ogg|mpe?g|avi|zip|gz|bz2?|rar|swf)$ {
                        root $root_path;
                        error_page 404 = @fallback;
        }
        location / {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
                        proxy_redirect http://localhost:81/ /;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
        location @fallback {
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:81;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }
}
```

But without success.

Comment: Have you set `RemoteIPHeader` in Apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nginx config looks good. You may need to add the following to your Apache config.

```
RemoteIPHeader X-Client-IP
```